# Seeing many open Elasticsearch connections even after using singleton pattern

Tags: elasticsearch

I just the following method for connection creation in ES:

```
public static Client getClient() {
    if (client == null) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put(CONFIG_CLUSTER_NAME, CLUSTER_NAME).build();
            client = new TransportClient(settings);
            for (String address : transportAddress ) {
                ((TransportClient) client).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(address, transportPort));
            }
            logger.info("Elastic search client initialized");
        }
    }
    logger.info("Returning the existing client");
    return client;
}
```

But for this application, when I ran netstat on that host, I saw many open connections:

```
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:59380  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:48829  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:42944  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:42838  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:8080   ::ffff:*.*.*.*:57649  ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:55154      ::ffff:*.*.*.*:3306       ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      1 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:36889  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   FIN_WAIT1   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:42829  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:37169  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:59390  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:58283  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:59383  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:55855  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:48823  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   ESTABLISHED 6552/java           
tcp        0      1 ::ffff:*.*.*.*:36884  ::ffff:*.*.*.*:9300   FIN_WAIT1   -
```

I have removed the ip with .... But there are many more open connections than this.

Questions:

1. **How do I manually go and close all these connections?**
2. **Is there any mistake in connection creation?**
3. **Sometimes, even if ES is running and connection is also created from java application, it doesn't get any response from ES. After restarting the java application, it returns result for the same query. It feels like the existing connection has become. So when I restart the app, it creates a new connection. And I start getting responses again. After a while, once it stops. How should I analyze this?**

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the question 3. That behavior is when you restart ES or your java application? and what means "it returns result for the same query"?

Comment: Yes. When I restart the java application, it creates a new connection to ES. After that, I get the response from ES. It feels like the previous connection had become stale.

Comment: Can you show the way you make the queries?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch creates multiples connections with every node (this is a really usual thing in server-client applications).

In earlier ES versions, there was three different class of connections:

- Low: connections for batch oriented APIs with high payload, like bulk operations.
- Med: connections for for the typical search / single doc index
- High: dedicated to state based operations.

Then ping was added, and now ES has 5 types of connections (you can check them [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/transport/netty/NettyTransport.java)):

- Recovery: for recovery of indexes.
- Bulk: for low priority bulk operations.
- Reg: for regular operations as queries.
- State: for state based operations.
- Ping: for ping between instances (for example, for fail detection).

You can control the number of each connection per node when you create the transport client with the setting with the configuration prefix *transport.connections_per_node*. So, for example, you can change the number of channels used for regular operations with transport.connections_per_node.reg

Answer (score 0):

A simple way for Connect the Elastic search and Java through

```
Client desclient=null;
```

//Applying Elastic search Setting

```
  Settings settingsdesc = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name","esclustername").build(); desclient = new TransportClient(settingsdesc).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("xx.xx.xx.xx",9300));
```

//Terminate the connection

```
desclient.close();
```